# How to get all form errors symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, constraints

Constrains:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=15)
 * @Assert\Regex(pattern = "/[0-9a-z]+/", message = "[regexp] ERROR")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "[notblank] ERROR")
 * @Assert\NotNull(message = "[notnull] ERROR")
 * @Assert\Length
 *          (
 *            min = "2",
 *            max = "4",
 *            minMessage = "[minlength] ERROR",
 *            maxMessage = "[maxlength] ERROR"
 *          )
 */
private $type_name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
 * @Assert\Regex(pattern = "/[0-9a-zA-Z\.\:\s]+/", message = "[regexp] ERROR")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "[notblank] ERROR")
 * @Assert\NotNull(message = "[notnull] ERROR")
 * @Assert\Length
 *          (
 *            min = "4",
 *            max = "50",
 *            minMessage = "[minlength] ERROR",
 *            maxMessage = "[maxlength] ERROR"
 *          )
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60)
 * @Assert\Regex(pattern = "/[0-9a-zA-Z\.\/]+/", message = "[regexp] ERROR")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "[notblank] ERROR")
 * @Assert\NotNull(message = "[notnull] ERROR")
 * @Assert\Length
 *          (
 *            min = "4",
 *            max = "60",
 *            minMessage = "[minlength] ERROR",
 *            maxMessage = "[maxlength] ERROR"
 *          )
 */
private $starterPath;
```

Controller (typesAction and typesAddAction):

```
public function typesAction()
{       
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $types = $em->getRepository('CsmBundle:Type')->findAll();

    $newType = new Type();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($newType)
        ->add('typeName', 'text')
        ->add('description', 'text')
        ->add('starterPath', 'text')
        ->getForm();

    return $this->render('CsmBundle:Root:types.html.twig', array(
        'types' => $types,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}

public function typesAddAction(Request $request)
{
    $newType = new Type();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($newType)
        ->add('typeName', 'text')
        ->add('description', 'text')
        ->add('starterPath', 'text')
        ->getForm();

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($newType);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('root_types'));
        }
        else
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $types = $em->getRepository('CsmBundle:Type')->findAll();

            return $this->render('CsmBundle:Root:types.html.twig', array(
                'types' => $types,
                'form' => $form->createView()
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

types.html.twig:

```
...
<form class="well" action="{{ path('root_types_add') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Adding New Type</legend>
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="100" align="left"><strong>Type name:</strong></td><td>{{ form_widget(form.typeName, { 'attr': {'class': 'txt'} }) }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left"><strong>Description:</strong></td><td>{{ form_widget(form.description, { 'attr': {'class': 'txt'} }) }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left"><strong>Starter:</strong></td><td>{{ form_widget(form.starterPath, { 'attr': {'class': 'txt'} }) }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">{{ form_errors(form) }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">{{ form_rest(form) }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right"><button style="" class="btn btn-large btn-success" value="add" name="add">Add!</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
</form>
...
```

Problem there: got error only for first field (typeName).
If i input incorrect data to all fields from HTML form, i got only(!) one error for first field (typeName).
If i input incorrect data to second (description) and third (starterPath) fields - i have no error.

Comment: are the errors just not appearing in the template or does your form consider input as valid which should be caught by the constraints for the other properties ?

Comment: No errors for description and starterPath fields at the controller code and at the twig template! As if the $description's constraints and starterPath's constraints does not exist. If i call $form->getErrors(), i got error only for first field (typeName), but if call $form->getErrorsAsString(), i get true results and it shows all errors.

Comment: Just to understand it right ..."No errors for description and starterPath fields at the controller code" ... means `$form->isValid()` returns `true` ? ... while `$form->getErrorsAsString()` includes errors for the description and starterPath?

Comment: $form->isValid() return false. I don't have problems there. $form->getErrors() return form errors only for first form field (all three fields have incorrect values), but $form->getErrorsAsString() returns all form errors. If i set correct value for 1 field and set incorrect values for 2 and 3 fields method $form->getErrors() returns "Array ( ) 1". I can't get formatted errors with $form->getErrorsAsString() and can't get array of errors for transmit it to template.

Comment: `$form->getErrors()` only returns the errors of the form while `$form->getErrorsAsString()` includes the children's errors ... as you can see here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php#L741

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use `{{ form_row(form.name) }}` instead of `{{ form_widget(form.name)` inside your templates to resolve the issue....

`form_widget` only renders the field's html while `form_row` renders the combination of `form_label`, `form_widget` and `form_errors`.

Have a look at the documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-row-view-variables).

If your form bubbles up the errors as global errors try setting `error_bubbling` to `false` ( defaults to `true` ) inside your form's default options like this:

```
$this->createFormBuilder($entity, array(
        'error_bubbling' => false,
        'data_class'     => 'Vendor\MyBundle\Entity\Name',
        // ... more options 
     )
 )
```